# OpenGL FBO texture width height in games

Tags: opengl, graphics, framebuffer, fbo

I have a question regarding Frame buffer objects in games. If a user changes the screen resolution in a game multiple times, what happens with the FBO sizes for post-processing etc? Do you have to delete all the created FBO's and create new ones? Is it better to resize them? or is it better to create a handler that creates new ones if they do not already exist and save the old(the user may switch back to the old screen resolution) ones? (the latest proposal may consume a tremendous amount of graphics memory if the user is constantly changing the screen resolution).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of users do you have in mind who will be resizing your window often enough for this to an important design decision? :) They don't seem to have the attention span necessary to play a game.

Comment: It should happen infrequently enough that the user simply accepts missing post-processing effects for 1-2 frames or an unusual delay before the first fully formed frame appears after resizing. Even more so now that temporal reprojection is becoming common.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman :P Just thinking of the worst case scenario, if a user is trying to find the best screen resolution for higher FPS/Quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, it is not really a problem to have some latences when you "resize" your window. When you resize the window, I guess you don't care about performances. According to me, when you resize the window, you are not really playing, and when you are playing, generally you use full screen mode.
So there is two possibilities : The first one, you fix size of all your frame buffers, it could be ok for simple game but not really suitable for "complex games".

The second one is approximately what you said.
FBO exist for rendering something to them and nowadays it could be dynamic, so the only purpose to keep several size of fbo is to eschew latencies when you resize. IMHO, you can don't care about these kind of latences and just remove and create again FBOs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What about memory fragmentation in V-RAM?  Something to consider when removing and recreating?

Comment: To me, if you really care about memory fragmentation in V-RAM, you should switch to Vulkan x).

To be more serious, I guess be confident into the driver is not a bad idea. For example, if you alloc 100M of video ram, and just after you remove and realloc 50M, it is highly probable that it will use the same area

Comment: But it will be much worse if the user have a 4k screen. Let's say that the user plays the game with a screen resolution of 1920*1080 and after couple of minutes, switching to 2560*1440, and again to 3840*2160. This will be critical if you have large G-buffers and other buffers for post-processing. It would be nice to know how the big companies handles the memory for the Fbos.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about anything crazy low-level VRAM-related like that even in Vulkan. If you look at the way residency is managed in DXGI 1.4 (for D3D12), the driver has a lot of freedom even in these so-called low-level APIs. You tell them what pool of memory to place the stuff in (don't have a lot of choices for render targets) and then whether it's required to be resident or not. Memory is completely virtualized and the fact that resources are partitioned into different pools further prevents serious fragmentation issues. You are nowhere near as low-level as you might be lead to believe :)

Comment: I don't know for big companies. But maybe you should take a look to virtual texturing with Sparse Textures. This feature allows you to manage yourself the memory and make it resident or not

Comment: I didn't play a lot with Vulkan, but I remember that it is a good idea to allocate a big chunk in once. And that could be help to solve the fragmentation, am I wrong?

Comment: Andon M. Coleman. You're probably right. Especially when I found this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.GetTemporary.html, In Unity, they deallocate/destroy the temporary textures when they aren't used for a couple of frames.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to touch Vulkan either. I was just pointing out that the framebuffer for drawing and texture memory are different types of resources. When left completely to the driver to manage this stuff in a higher-level API like D3D11, DXGI 1.4 discusses some details that nobody ever talks about for GL. The driver expects to move textures in/out of VRAM (and even duplicates them in system RAM) as necessary to make this all work but doesn't have this same freedom for rendertargets. I expect GL works the same, but good luck getting details on these lower-level implementation details.

Comment: Antoine Morrier and Andon M. Coleman, thanks for all the information. I will most likely implement something similar that can be found in Unity, i.e. RenderTexture.GetTemporary.

Comment: You are welcome.
According to you Andon M. Coleman, sparse textures are not the solution to this problem?